# Parse local datastore and PFObject subclasses

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So I was delighted when Parse local data store got introduced in iOS and quickly added couple of functionalities using it. In one place i persist certain collection of objects using

```
[Spot pin]
```

FYI Spot is a subclass of PFObject. 
Now, i open up another screen where that object that i just persisted is part of the PFQuery result, however i keep getting exception:

> [PFObject name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2716422e0

Looks like Parse in this case is referencing the pinned object as their doc states:

> When enabled, there will only be one instance of any given PFObject.
>   For example, imagine you have an instance of the "GameScore" class
>   with an objectId of "xWMyZ4YEGZ", and then you issue a PFQuery for all
>   instances of "GameScore" with that objectId. The result will be the
>   same instance of the object you already have in memory.

but rather than my subclass it's thinking it's just a PFObject... is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out myself. Turns out you have to call registerSubclass method on the subclasses **BEFORE** you even initialize Parse with it's AppId and clientKey and enable localDataStore. So the code should look:

```
[Spot registerSubclass];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"XXX" clientKey:@"XXX"];
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
```

Comment: This worked for me. The mistake is calling registerSubclass after enableLocalDatastore.  "registerSubclass" should be called before "enableLocalDatastore"

Comment: Can I use parse just to store data locally as a replacement of core-data?

Answer (score 0):

... call [Parse enableLocalDatastore] before your call to setApplicationId:clientKey:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
  [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
  [Parse setApplicationId:@"parseAppId" clientKey:@"parseClientKey"];
}
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore-pinning

and in .m of your Spot subclass:

```
+ (void)load{

    [self registerSubclass];
}
```