# Cannot access property from a class which is subclassed from PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

When I tried to get records from the local data store in iOS, objects are returning but if I access a custom property it gives an error **"-[PFObject name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"**. Below is a sample code snippet.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query fromPinWithName:@"MyChanges"];

[[query findInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

  NSArray *scores = task.result;

  for (GameScore *score in scores) {
    NSLog(@"score is : %d %d", score.highScore, score.name);
  }
}];
```

and my subclass is like

```
@interface GameScore : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *highScore;

@end
```

And I am saving them as

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
  [GameScore pinAllInBackground:objects withName:@"MyChanges" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

  }];
}];
```

Comment: Are you initializing your subclass in your appDelegate?

Comment: @RyanKreager  Yes, I did. It is working when I am getting the results from parse. Problem with getting locally stored results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exact same issue as you, asked & answered it in this question: [Parse local datastore and PFObject subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510362/parse-local-datastore-and-pfobject-subclasses)

Simply make sure you register your subclasses before doing anything else with Parse framework.

Comment: This worked for me. "registerSubclass" should be called before "enableLocalDatastore" when we use local data store.